# matplotlib colourbar custom colour 1 value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I want a normal `colorbar` but with some differences in color for a specific value.

My data covers range `(0,1)` but I want to pass some values that are outside that range (because they are errors), and I want to see them with another color outside the main range.

So what I want is to assign the color black to -1 values and a normal colorbar to those in the range of `(0,1)`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is but you don't need to rebuild a colormap for your specific case (which takes some effort). You can keep those values aside using the `vmin` and `vmax` to say what are the limits for your data and than specify the color for all values below or over those limits (using `set_under` and `set_over`).

Check the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 10, 100), np.linspace(0, 10, 100))
im = (x**2 + y**2)/100-0.5 # Creating synthetic data for your example

p = plt.imshow(im.T, vmin=0, vmax=1, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest') # Set limits with vmin and vmax
p.cmap.set_under('k')  # Set color under lower limit (k for black)
p.cmap.set_over('w')  # Set color over upper limit (w for white)
plt.show()
```

, which results in this:

[image: Stating color for limits of data in matplotlib]

Everything below 0 is black, everything over 1 is white.